History of linguistics reference request
I just finished Randy A. Harris's The Linguistics Wars, and I found it very illuminating. I was looking for personal endorsements of some history of linguistics that are used in academia to give a full history of the adoption of traditional grammars and study of language. I went to Google Books and did a search for "history of linguistics", but as a non-linguist with a fair amount of reading about the linguistic turn and philosophy of language, I was looking for something that might be authoritative in the same vein as Russell's A History of Western Philosophy, which I consider authoritative insofar as it was written by a prominent philosopher and is a dated and imperfect, but fairly detailed and comprehensive treatment of the matter.
Thanks!

https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/cambridge-history-of-linguistics/9E944650E14861BEAFEDF5CE242618FC Cambridge History of Linguistics, for example. And the Oxford Handbook of the History of Linguistics https://www.amazon.com/Oxford-Handbook-History-Linguistics-Handbooks/dp/0199585849

@Lambie Thanks. I should've thought of those presses. But they mondo costly.

Well, they'd be in a good library, wouldn't they?

@Lambie I'm not for renting. To read a book once is not to really have read it. ; )

Reference books are expensive. Buy a second-hand copy. Libraries lend books for free, they don't rent them.

When you can read German, I recommend this book: Hans Arens. Sprachwissenschaft Der Gang Ihrer Entwicklung Von Der Antike Bis Zur Gegenwart, Zweite, durchgesehene und stark erweiterte Auflage. Karl Alber, Freiburg/München 1969 (Als Taschenbuch: Fischer Athenäum Taschenbücher, Frankfurt/Main 1974, Band I: ISBN 3-8072-2077-1; Band II: ISBN 3-8072-2078-X).
Unfortunately, this book is now more than 50 year old, and it doesn't cover all the new developments since 1969.

Vielen Dank. Das ist eine Möglischkeit, aber erst muß mein Vokabular verbessern. Es ist ein Kampf, um Wittgenstein lessen, also wäre ein wissenschaftliches Lehrbuch vermutlich schwieriger.

https://www.amazon.com/Sprachwissenschaft-H-Arens/dp/B0000BFX1M

@JD Your amazon link goes to the 1955 hardcover edition, I do not recommend this one, given the existence of a 2nd younger edition with extended content. Make sure to get the 2nd edition or later.

@JD BTW, I consider Wittgenstein a harder read than Arens. After all, Wittgenstein was a philosopher, and German-language philosophers tend to be very hard to read, but Arens a linguist.
